# What is the best way to find N consecutive elements of a sorted version of an unordered array?

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting

For instance: I have an unsorted list A of 10 elements. I need the sublist of `k` consecutive elements from `i` through `i+k-1` of the sorted version of A.

```
Example:  
Input: A { 1, 6, 13, 2, 8, 0, 100, 3, -4, 10 }  
       k = 3  
       i = 4  
Output: sublist B { 2, 3, 6 }
```

Comment: well, [sort it](https://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort)?

Comment: What are the tradeoffs? As @FelixPalmen told, you can achieve it by sorting, but are there any specific constraints?

Comment: I was thinking about just sorting it first and then getting k thru k+i elements. But that definatelly is not the best way. There is a selection algorithm that can effectively find Kth element of unsorted list. I think I know how to solve this problem effectively for i=1.

Comment: Say I have a list of 1 billion elements and I only need 5 of them, say 996 though 1000. I do not want to sort the whole array. That would require a lot of time and space as well. There is gotta be a better way)))

Comment: I think to achieve this, you can use `quickselect` method used in Quicksort. You would need to select the pivot elements based on your range.

Comment: From `i` to `i+k` is **not** k elements. From `2` to `2+2` you get three elements (indexes 2, 3, and 4).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `i` and `k` are specified, you can use a specialized version of quicksort where you stop recursion on parts of the array that fall outside of the `i .. i+k` range.  If the array can be modified, perform this partial sort in place, if the array cannot be modified, you will need to make a copy.

Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

// Partial Quick Sort using Hoare's original partition scheme
void partial_quick_sort(int *a, int lo, int hi, int c, int d) {
    if (lo < d && hi > c && hi - lo > 1) {
        int x, pivot = a[lo];
        int i = lo - 1;
        int j = hi;

        for (;;) {
            while (a[++i] < pivot)
                continue;

            while (a[--j] > pivot)
                continue;

            if (i >= j)
                break;

            x = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = x;
        }
        partial_quick_sort(a, lo, j + 1, c, d);
        partial_quick_sort(a, j + 1, hi, c, d);
    }
}

void print_array(const char *msg, int a[], int count) {
    printf("%s: ", msg);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf("%d%c", a[i], " \n"[i == count - 1]);
    }
}

int int_cmp(const void *p1, const void *p2) {
    int i1 = *(const int *)p1;
    int i2 = *(const int *)p2;
    return (i1 > i2) - (i1 < i2);
}

#define MAX 1000000

int main(void) {
    int *a = malloc(MAX * sizeof(*a));
    clock_t t;
    int i, k;

    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        a[i] = rand();
    }
    i = 20;
    k = 10;
    printf("extracting %d elements at %d from %d total elements\n",
           k, i, MAX);
    t = clock();
    partial_quick_sort(a, 0, MAX, i, i + k);
    t = clock() - t;
    print_array("partial qsort", a + i, k);
    printf("elapsed time: %.3fms\n", t * 1000.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    t = clock();
    qsort(a, MAX, sizeof *a, int_cmp);
    t = clock() - t;
    print_array("complete qsort", a + i, k);
    printf("elapsed time: %.3fms\n", t * 1000.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    return 0;
}
```

Running this program with an array of 1 million random integers, extracting the 10 entries of the sorted array starting at offset 20 gives this output:

```
extracting 10 elements at 20 from 1000000 total elements
partial qsort: 33269 38347 39390 45413 49479 50180 54389 55880 55927 62158
elapsed time: 3.408ms
complete qsort: 33269 38347 39390 45413 49479 50180 54389 55880 55927 62158
elapsed time: 149.101ms
```

It is indeed much faster (**20x** to **50x**) than sorting the whole array, even with a simplistic choice of pivot. Try multiple runs and see how the timings change.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is just [Quickselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect)

Comment: @JimMischel: it is a generalized version of QuickSelect. QuickSelect finds the k smallest values in an unordered array. The above code extracts any range from the sorted set. I don't claim ownership on this idea, I was just born when Tim Hoare invented QuickSort and QuickSelect in 1961 and the generalized version is described in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_sorting#Specialised_sorting_algorithms

Answer (score 2):

An idea could be to scan your array for bigger or equal numbers of i and smaller or equal numbers of i+k and add them to another list/container.

This will take you O(n) and give an unordered list of the numbers you need. Then you sort that list O(nlogn) and you are done.

For really big arrays the advantage of this method is that you will sort a smaller list of numbers. (given that the k is relatively small).

Comment: How do you plan on getting the (i)th and the (i+k)th element in `O(n)`. Elaborating on that would be useful.

Comment: The way we do it right now is as follows: We start reading from collection A and creat a sorted sub-collection B of (k+i) elements. Each time we fetch a new element from A we compare it to the last element of B. If it's greater we move on, if it's smaller we insert it into the right place in B. Once all elements of A are processed, we just get last k elements of B. If both i and k are small the algorithm works in almost O(n) time using O(k+i) space. But if i = 1000000 and k = 5 and size of A is a billion, we start running into problems. The space is the main issue for us.

Comment: @imoutidi i and k are not numbers of the array A. i and k are places in the sorted version of A

Comment: @DmitriiDunaev you are right. I didn't understood what you meant. 
The think is that there is no way to know the positions of each number you need before sorting A. The method you are using is interesting but as you say consumes memory.

Comment: @DmitriiDunaev: The heap selection algorithm that I outline is generally the same as the algorithm you describe in your comment. Only that I use a heap rather than a sorted array to hold the (k+i) elements. The heap is a more efficient priority queue. Your algorithm takes O(n*(i+k)) time. The heap selection algorithm is O(n*log(i+k)).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Quickselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect), or a heap selection algorithm to get the `i+k` smallest items. Quickselect works in-place, but it modifies the original array. It also won't work if the list of items is larger than will fit in memory. Quickselect is O(n), but with a fairly high constant. When the number of items you are selecting is a very small fraction of the total number of items, the heap selection algorithm is faster.

The idea behind the heap selection algorithm is that you initialize a max-heap with the first `i+k` items. Then, iterate through the rest of the items. If an item is smaller than the largest item on the max-heap, remove the largest item from the max-heap and replace it with the new, smaller item. When you're done, you have the first `i+k` items on the heap, with the largest k items at the top.

The code is pretty simple:

```
heap = new max_heap();
Add first `i+k` items from a[] to heap
for all remaining items in a[]
    if item < heap.peek()
        heap.pop()
        heap.push(item)
    end-if
end-for

// at this point the smallest i+k items are on the heap
```

This requires O(i+k) extra memory, and worst case running time is O(n log(i+k)). When `(i+k)` is less than about 2% of `n`, it will usually outperform Quickselect.

For much more information about this, see my blog post [When theory meets practice](http://blog.mischel.com/2011/10/25/when-theory-meets-practice/).

By the way, you can optimize your memory usage somewhat based on `i`. That is, if there are a billion items in the array and you want items 999,999,000 through 999,999,910, the standard method above would require a huge heap. But you can re-cast that problem to one in which you need to select the smallest of the last 1,000 items. Your heap then becomes a min-heap of 1,000 items. It just takes a little math to determine which way will require the smallest heap.

That doesn't help much, of course, if you want items 600,000,000 through 600,000,010, because your heap still has 400 million items in it.

It occurs to me, though, that if time isn't a huge issue, you can just build the heap in the array in-place using Floyd's algorithm, pop the first `i` items like you would with heap sort, and the next `k` items are what you're looking for. This would require constant extra space and O(n + (i+k)*log(n)) time.

Come to think of it, you could implement the heap selection logic with a heap of (i+k) items (as described above) in-place, as well. It would be a little tricky to implement, but it wouldn't require any extra space and would have the same running time O(n*log(i+k)).

Note that both would modify the original array.

Comment: But you left out the punch line! You can find the i+k smallest items, then from that set find the i biggest.

Comment: If i have a relatively small number of k and a big n, will it be faster to use selection algorithm K times?

Comment: That would require O(kn) time and just O(k) space, would not it?

Comment: It requires O (i+k) space, and O (n*log (i+k)) time in the worst case. See my blog post for details.

Comment: No, it would not be faster to use the selection algorithm k times. The limiting factor here isn't `k`, but `(i+k)`. For example, the heap selection algorithm will find items 200-210 faster than it will find items 1000-1010. In the first case, it requires a heap of 210 items. The second required a heap of 1010 items.

Comment: @DmitriiDunaev: See my update at the end. You can do the heap selection in-place without requiring any extra space.

Comment: @JimMischel thank you Jim for your answers and for your blog as well. Bookmarked. I should have mentioned earlier that we do not have array A in memory. I do not even know the size of A before hand. It's on a disk. I think the easiest way would be to store elements of A as a sorted list on a disk. Adding elements to it would then take some extra time but retrieving them would be much faster.

Comment: @DmitriiDunaev: Not being able to hold the array in memory changes the problem quite a bit. If you know that `(i+k)` elements will fit in memory, then you can do the simple heap selection that I described first (and that my blog describes). Otherwise you can, you can build some number of smaller heaps in memory, store them in temporary files, and then do a multi-way merge, to get the first `(i+k)` items.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is modify [heapsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort), such that you will first create the heap, but then pop the first `i` elements. The next `k` elements you pop form the heap will be your result. Discarding the `n - i - k` elements remaining let's the algorithm terminate early.

The result will be in `O((i + k) log n)` which is in `O(n log n)`, but is significantly faster with relative low values for `i` and `k`.

Comment: That should work but the downside of this approach is that we first need to build the heap, which requires O(n) of space.

Comment: @DmitriiDunaev: You can build the binary heap in-place in O(n) time. The problem is that the algorithm, although asymptotically O(n), has a fairly high constant. Building the heap takes longer than Quickselect, and also longer than the heap selection method that I describe.